# When moving data from one hard drive to another, how much free space does the source drive need?

Tags: hard-drive

Exactly how much free space on the source drive is needed to allow the file transfer to complete successfully?

Can I move data from a completely full drive to a larger drive without needing to delete any data first?

Comment: If your moving data from the source to the desination the source doesn't need any free space.

Comment: @Ramhound: Yes that's what I mean. You could post as an answer.

Comment: I will let somebody else answer it.  Your question body isn't clear, and I don't answer questions, when I have to answer the question in the title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally the answer here is none.  At least if you are talking about regular files that are not in use.

There are some special cases if you were moving a live database, or other in-use files combined with volume snapshots or something.